# How to modify the EE code for detailed control of weblog link conversion preferences?

Tags: javascript, expressionengine

Have a site running on ExpressionEngine 1.7 (yeah, it's old). The issue is that when weblog preferences are set to "auto convert links and emails to URLs" we get a message that ".(JavaScript must be enabled to view this email address)" when someone posts an email in the comment section (web urls convert fine). If we turn off the conversion in preferences, the email addresses show fine but we lose the autoconverted web links. Does anyone know where we would modify the EE code that controls the url conversion to keep the web urls link conversion but stop converting the email addresses?

Answer (score 0):

You might have sorted this on your own by now but just in case...

Looks like you want the `auto_linker` function and the `encode_email` function.  Both can be found in typography file:

```
/system/core/core.typography.php
```

Actually before you go hacking that, it looks like you might be able to just change a value in that same file.  I'm seeing:

```
var $encode_email               = TRUE;
```

Try setting to FALSE.

This line looks promising too:

```
var $encode_type                = 'javascript'; // javascript or noscript
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice on that. It's not clear how the typography file interacts with the settings in the control panel, since the control panel allows different settings for each template, and content vs comments in each template, yet typography file is site-wide.

In any case, we discovered that the simpler solution is just to turn off the EE autoconvert of emails and links for each template's content. That eliminates the javascript error, yet the urls and emails are still linked. Presumably, because the browsers now do that linking natively, so there no longer is a need for EE to do it?

Comment: Else, some other feature of EE is doing the conversion without javascript.